# LOAD XML Unrecognized statement type

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

If I run a simple MySQL query in phpMyAdmin:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE "C:/Users/user/Documents/file.xml"
INTO TABLE mytable
CHARACTER SET utf8
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<tag>'
```

it's giving me "Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOAD" at position 0)" as well as "#7890 - Can't find file " if the file is not found.

However, if the file is actually found, it proceeds to run the query, saving 0 results into the table, although it still doesn't recognize the statement type.

I am using MySQL version 5.7.19, PhpMyAdmin version  4.7.4

Any ideas as to why it wouldn't recognize XML statement or, why it would proceed with empty result, if it wouldn't recognize the statement?

Edit: To add some insight, here's what I tried:

- LOAD DATA - works just fine, loads the xml into database, only it loads the data as urls into the first column, which is to be expected, but the query works.
- Using Microsoft's sample xml file (books.xml) from: [Microsoft sample xml page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx) to make sure my xml is not wrong. - results are still empty

MySQL just seems to think LOAD "XML" is not a statement type, as if I was using a pre 5.2. verison or something, while I am on 5.7., using phpmyadmin and WAMP server on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin is a third-party web-based GUI tool that isn't affiliated to neither MySQL nor Oracle Corporation. Said that...

- Error messages generated by MySQL Server don't look like that. In fact, `Unrecognized statement type` does not seem to be a valid [server error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-messages-server.html).
- If you get a syntax error but the statement actually runs, it's most likely a PhpMyAdmin issue.
- You can always double-check with e.g. the [official command-line client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).
- [LOAD XML](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-xml.html) documentation warns:

  > the transfer of the XML file from the client host to the server host is initiated by the MySQL server.[...] In a Web environment, clients usually connect to MySQL from a Web server. A user that can run any command against the MySQL server can use LOAD XML LOCAL to read any files to which the Web server process has read access. In this environment, the client with respect to the MySQL server is actually the Web server, not the remote program being run by the user who connects to the Web server.

  Thus a file system path like `C:/Users/user/Documents/file.xml` will not work unless you're running PhpMyAdmin in your own computer and the user it runs as has privileges to read files in your own user profile.

Comment: Edited my question a little. 
I am actually running PhpMyAdmin in my own computer, with the needed privileges. Additionally, the xml file loads just fine with the command LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, only I would very much like to  use LOAD XML, instead of working out how to insert the data into corresponding columns while using LOAD DATA. Thing is, the XML statement type gets refused either by MySQL, PhpMyAdmin, or anything else, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: If PhpMyAdmin does not even recognise the statement I don't think it'll process the file upload. Most likely it's MySQL Server the one that's trying to read it.

Comment: For some reason, it actually just started adding the xml into the database properly now, after fiddling with everything I could (and not really remembering what it was), while it still states the statement type is unrecognised, and when it proceeds, it then states there were 0 rows added. Still, the database gets updated suddenly, and I can't figure out why, or why it wasn't in the first place, and generally what's going on in phpMyAdmin now.